# Grails render view from different plugin when deployed

Tags: grails

I have a problem, which only is an issue when my application is deployed - there is no issue when developing.

I have 2 controlleres. One controller residing i a plugin which the second is extending. There exists a specific template in a view folder - `/templates/_mytemplate.gsp` in the "main" project -that is, not in the plugin.

The "common-controller" has a method for rendering various templates based on a string. And this is where the trouble starts. Using:

```
String summary = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "/mycontroller/templates/_mytemplates.gsp", model: [foo: bar])
```

Works perfectly fine in development but when war-deployed, the string is empty. I have narrowed the problem down to be of `resolveSearchPaths` method in `DefaultGroovyPageLocator` [[1]](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/discovery/DefaultGroovyPageLocator.html) which differentiates the lookup path.

Anyone? What would be reasonable solution? Preferable the templates are not located in the plugin....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid stupid stupid!

Developing on windows - deploying to Unix. So forgot a camelcase T <- which works on Windows not on Unix :)

So to make it work:

```
String summary = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "/mycontroller/templates/_my**T**emplates.gsp", model: [foo: bar])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a release a few days back and used something like:

```
try {
        //look for template in the main app
        def html = render(template:'/mycontroller/templates/mytemplates', model: [foo: bar])
        if(html && html.size() > 0) {
            render html
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //bad way to handle template not found.
    }
    //fallback on the template defined in the plugin
    render(plugin:'myPlugin', template:'/mycontroller/templates/mytemplates', model: [foo: bar])
```

This probably isn't the best way to handle this issue but at least gets the deployed war working.